# How to create a csv Excel file from content in a gridview in WPF?

Tags: wpf, csv, gridview

I would like to export to a csv file the content of a gridview in WPF. Which is the best and efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) component to generate a CSV or simply use a StringBuilder instance to iterate through the contents of the columns in the WPF gridview, in similar pseudocode it would be like this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach row in grid
   foreach col in grid
      sb.Append(col + ", ");
   end foreach
   sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
end foreach

// Write out the StringBuilder instance to File
```

The above pseudocode iterates each row and each column, tacking on a delimiter for each column by using a comma.